# JQuery select Id question

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jquery question about selecting Id.

Basically, I call a javascript function from an onClick function which I pass in control Id and LabelId.

If I use document.getElementById, it will work, however, if I use jQuery selector, it's NOT working.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery.noConflict();
    function ToggleProgressEnable(valueofRadio, controlId, labelId) {

//Comments: the following will work.  
//        var control = document.getElementById(controlId);
//        var label = document.getElementById(labelId);

//The following is not working.
        var control = jQuery("'#" + controlId + "'");
        var label = jQuery("'#" + labelId + "'");
        if (control != null && label!=null) {
            //alert(control.Id);
            //alert(control.disabled);
            if (valueofRadio == "yes") {
                control.disabled = false;                
                label.disabled = false;
            }
            else if (valueofRadio == "no") {
            control.disabled = true;
            control.value = "";
            label.disabled = true;
            }
            //alert(control.disabled);
        }
    }    
</script>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var control = jQuery("'#" + controlId + "'");        
var label = jQuery("'#" + labelId + "'");
```

you're doing your selectors wrong. get rid of your single quotes and just use your double quotes:

```
var control = $("#" + controlId);        
var label = $("#" + labelId);
```

Comment: +1 - Maybe show the correct usage instead of quoting the wrong one?

Comment: definitely.  it looks like he's composing the source code instead of the needed value.

Comment: when use jquery select id, did it return array or the single element?

Comment: technically it returns an array, but if there's only one element in the array (for instance, if you're using best practices and have one unique element per page) then it will return that single element. if you do something like $("a") it will get all your <a> tags.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
jQuery('#' + controlId);
```

Otherwise, you're searching for '#controlId', which is not a valid selector.

Answer (score 1):

You are receiving a jQuery object, not a DOM element. You should use:

```
control.val()
```

for example to get the value...

Oh and i second Jasons answer:

```
jQuery('#' + controlId);
```

should do fine...

Comment: i didn't downvote you, but you have a . where there should be a +

Comment: Wasn't blaming you, just the anonymous voter... Sorry for the . too much php today :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this:

```
var control = jQuery("#" + controlId);
var label = jQuery("#" + labelId);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    var control = jQuery("#" + controlId);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest passing the controlId and labelId as selectors or elements rather than as strings.  Take full advantage of the fact that you can pass objects as arguments.

```
var control = $('#myControl');
var label = $('#myLabel');

ToggleProgressEnable(5, control, label);
```